# How to use nanoid module on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, module

I know that maybe this question is very silly, but I can't make [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) to work on my NodeJS app.

I already read the docs.

This is my app.js configuration:

```
var nanoid = require("nanoid");
var ID = nanoid();
```

And I get the error message:

```
TypeError: nanoid is not a function
  at Object.<anonymous> (myapp.js directory)
```

Maybe I need to import the function inside nanoid but I dont know how to do it. Help would be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: `var nanoid = require("nanoid").default`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

nanoid is a function inside the module try this

```
var { nanoid } = require("nanoid");
var ID = nanoid();
```

Comment: @NeriyaBar-Iev Thanks Man, that's work. It was driving me crazy

Comment: As of 2023, this no longer works

Comment: Does anyone has a solution as of 2023 for this no longer working?

Comment: use nanoid v3 to use commonjs syntax. For more info look here https://github.com/ai/nanoid/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#40

Answer (score 0):

in new method ES6 must use IMPORT like

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
var ID = nanoid();
```